# Cross join causes value to be repeated

Tags: mysql

I am using `CROSS JOIN` in my SQL query below

```
SELECT 
  store.ACTIVITY_MTH,
  Cmps_Util,
  SUM(store.Renew) AS GR
FROM
  store 
  CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      SUM(revenue.rev_attained) * 100 AS Cmps_Util 
    FROM
      revenue 
    WHERE revenue.start_date BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-10-31' 
      AND revenue.metric_id = 182 
      AND revenue.id = 'PH') AS Cmps_Util 
WHERE 
  AND store.ACTIVITY_MTH BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-10-31' 
GROUP BY store.ACTIVITY_MTH
```

This results in the following response

```
ACTIVITY_MTH    Cmps_Util   GR
2014-05-01      1.2362      356
2014-06-01      1.2362      789
2014-07-01      1.2362      45
2014-08-01      1.2362      1567
2014-09-01      1.2362      45
2014-10-01      1.2362      786
```

Notice that the Column `Cmps_Util` all the values are the same . This is the `Cross Joined` column. How can i stop it form repeating? Notice the GR column the data is not repeated. Basically i want the data in Cmps_Util for a particular month line up with the `Activity_MTH` column. (the `Revenue` table also has `revenue.start_date` which is being used for Cmps_Util). If revenue table does not have a entry for that month then `NULL` like below.

```
ACTIVITY_MTH    Cmps_Util   GR
2014-05-01      null        356
2014-06-01      2.523       789
2014-07-01      null        45
2014-08-01      1.2362      1567
2014-09-01      1.6         45
2014-10-01      1.86        786
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `CROSS JOIN`. I believe you just want a boring old `LEFT JOIN` here, but your subquery needs to  include the  start of the month for each `Revenue.start_date` in your subquery so it can join to the `Activity_Mth`

```
SELECT store.ACTIVITY_MTH,
    SUM(Cmps_Util.Cmps_Util),
    SUM(store.Renew) AS GR
FROM store
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT FIRST_DAY(revenue.start_date) AS start_date_month,
            SUM(revenue.rev_attained) * 100 AS Cmps_Util
        FROM revenue
        WHERE revenue.start_date BETWEEN '2014-05-01'
                AND '2014-10-31'
            AND revenue.metric_id = 182
            AND revenue.id = 'PH'
        GROUP BY 1
    ) AS Cmps_Util
    ON store.ACTIVITY_MTH = Cmps_Util.start_date_month
GROUP BY store.ACTIVITY_MTH
```

The problem is that `CROSS JOIN` is going to give you every value from `Cmps_Util` AND every value from `store` joined together in every possible combination. You, instead, were wanting to join on the month/date of the `revenue` table for each `Activit_mth` in the `store` table (I assumed).

Comment: it should be a left join since op wants null when there's no data

Comment: @FuzzyTree, Good call. I have edited to include that.

Comment: @FuzzyTree with a `Left Join` also need to include `Group By start_date_month`

Comment: @codeNinja, That `GROUP BY` is included in the subquery `cmps_utl` in the `GROUP BY 1` statement. I did just make a quick change to add `SUM(cmps_util.cmps_util)` in the main query too.

Comment: @FuzzyTree yup just saw the `Group by 1`. My bad. Didnt need the change to SUM(cmps_util.cmps_util). Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to left join 2 derived tables. The 1st derived table will contain the `gr` sum for each activity_mth and the 2nd will contain the `Cmps_Util` sum for each `start_date` (assuming all your `start_date` values are at the 1st of the month like activity_mth - otherwise you'll need to extract the 1st day from start_date ).

```
select t1.activity_mth, t2.cmps_util, t1.gr 
from (
    select 
        sum(renew) gr,
        activity_mth
    from store
    where activity_mth between '2014-05-01' and '2014-10-31'
    group by activity_mth
) t1 left join (
    select 
      start_date,
      sum(revenue.rev_attained) * 100 as cmps_util 
    from revenue 
    where revenue.start_date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-10-31' 
      and revenue.metric_id = 182 
      and revenue.id = 'ph'
    group by start_date
) t2 on t1.activity_mth = t2.start_date
```